# How to make Label element inline in nativescript?

Tags: android-layout, nativescript

I have **HTML** I want to give `border-bottom` property to the `<Label>` element which is a child of `<StackLayout>`.

My problem is the `border-bottom` is taking full width like a `div` in the web. I want this `Label` element to be inline like a `span` so that it's width should not be more than its content width.

```
    <StackLayout *ngIf="!places.length">
       <Label (tap)="onSearch()" class="fo-20 m-t-20 opensans-bold text-center p-b-5"
         borderBottomColor="#F16051" borderBottomWidth="2" text="View All Activities"></Label>
    </StackLayout>
```

Below is the layout I'm getting now. But I don't want that orange line to be end to end. Instead its width should always be equal to the text present inside that Label.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting `horizontalAlignment` on Label to `center`

```
<Label horizontalAlignment="center" ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of **StackLayout**, you can have **FlexboxLayout** with the `justifyContent="center"`.

```
<FlexboxLayout justifyContent="center" *ngIf="!places.length">
  <Label (tap)="onSearch()" class="fo-20 m-t-20 opensans-bold text-center p-b- 
   5" borderBottomColor="#F16051" borderBottomWidth="2" text="View All 
   Activities"> . 
  </Label>
</FlexboxLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `horizontalAlignment="center"` to the label. This will center the component, making it only the size it needs to have.

Example playground: https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-vue&id=8kZUFY